# Transparent I can be

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Transparent I can be
>
> Sometimes only one side can see
>
> Multiple of me on a screen to play or work
>
> A reflector for a smirk

**What am I?**

Comment: only one of you can we see or only one persone can see you?

Comment: @lois6b I meant one side, edited it, thank you :)

Comment: A [one-way mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_mirror) would be too easy, right? But it would fit for 1), 2) and 4), not sure about 3).

Comment: @LukasRotter You are in the right direction my friend

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a

> (tinted) window

Transparent I can be

> If there's a glass inside a standard window, it's most likely transparent

Sometimes only one side can see

> Only people on one side of a tinted window, for example inside a car, can see outside.

Multiple of me on a screen to play or work

> <strike>Multiple opened GUI-programs (windows) visible on a computer screen: Games or tools.</strike>
> The plural of 'window' is 'windows', the operating system. Also, thanks to [smriti](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22882/smriti) who figured this out: The windows (OS) symbol has 4 windows in it.

A reflector for a smirk

> Opposite of 2), it reflects when the tinted window is viewed from outside the car.

Comment: Very close, though the 3rd one is not quite right yet :)

Comment: @Foitn 3rd clue... is it refering to 'windows' as in OS?

Comment: @smriti YESSSSS, well done, though I had hoped that this riddle would be harder to crack...

Comment: @Foitn I don't understand... How can multiple Windows operating systems be visible on a single computer screen? Should 'screen' be in plural in your question?

Comment: Windows symbol has 4 windows in it, also there are different windows versions

Comment: @Foitn I think first two lines are dead giveaway.

Comment: @LukasRotter Not multiple windows OS, but the multiple of window is windows, which is the operating system...

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Mirror

Transparent I can be

> It can be transparent like in windshield in car

Sometimes only one side can see

> mirror that reflects you

Multiple of me on a screen to play or work

> Can't say. Perhaps refers to a computer screen.

A reflector for a smirk

> Side mirrors in the car.

Comment: You are thinking in the right direction but this answer sadly is wrong